# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class Login

Tags: java, servlets

HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class Login

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class Login

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class Login
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



root cause 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Login
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.TTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

Comment: Can you show your servlet class and the place where servlet is being invoked?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you're trying to do and what is it that you've already tried out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class pkg.coreServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921540/http-status-500-error-instantiating-servlet-class-pkg-coreservlet)

Comment: "root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Login": pretty clear.

Comment: Classes in the default (nameless) package or not visible outside the default package.