# HTTP Status 500-Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat8.5

I just learnt `Servlets` and tried implementing a basic `Servlet` . I am getting an error like this

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
>
> Message Error instantiating servlet class

I have tried to solve the issue by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921540/http-status-500-error-instantiating-servlet-class-pkg-coreservlet)  link but nothing worked out.
The following is my project structure

[image]

The content of my `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="welcome">Click to call Servlet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of my `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>final</display-name>    
<servlet>
<servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My `Test` class

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Test extends HttpServlet {
     private String mymsg;
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 102831973239L;

       public void init() throws ServletException {
          mymsg = "Hello World!";
       }

       public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
          HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException 
       {

          // Setting up the content type of webpage
          response.setContentType("text/html");

          // Writing message to the web page
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println("<h1>" + mymsg + "</h1>");
       }



}
```

I am pretty new to this stuff and these are the error messages on my `tomcat` console

```
Nov 06, 2019 11:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [sample] as unavailable
Nov 06, 2019 11:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [sample]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:763)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Same setup is working fine for me. Would it be possible for you to share logs! if you have any? Even try removing instance and clean tomcat.

Comment: @ialam  I have  updated the logs . Tried cleaning tomcat but no use

Comment: There seems to be problem with your project. It's not able to find Test class. Try deleting the Test file and create it again or delete the project and recreate it if 1st one doesn't work.

Comment: Declare and put your class into a `package`.