# Tomcat - Error instantiating servlet class - intelij

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

After creating a project in intelij and starting Tomcat Server I successfully get my index.jsp page.

But when I try to open HelloServlet.java I get: "Error instantiating servlet class" error.

And then when I reload this page I get the 404 error: "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

***This code definitely works on another PC with Tomcat, but doesn't on mine.***

**HelloServlet.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

***web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

***index.jsp***

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= "Hello World!" %></h1>
    <br/>
    <a href="HelloServlet">Hello Servlet</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Project Structure***

```
|____resources
|____webapp
| |____index.jsp
| |____WEB-INF
| | |____web.xml
|____java
| |____HelloServlet.java
```

What should I do to fix my problem?

Comment: In which package do you have `HelloServlet.java`?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921540/http-status-500-error-instantiating-servlet-class-pkg-coreservlet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)

Comment: ```HelloServlet.java``` is located in java folder without any packages

Comment: This answer doesn't help

Comment: @АлександрЛисов: that is precisely the problem. Classes in the default package (_"folder without any packages"_) are **not** accessible to classes in a package (Tomcat's classes). You need to put the `HelloServlet` class in a package.

Comment: So I've put ```HelloServlet``` in a package and edited ```web.xml```. 

Now the path is:  ```java/web/HelloServlet.java```.

In web XML added "web." to servlet-name, so I got: <servlet-class>web.HelloServlet</servlet-class>.

But still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem installing Tomcat 8.5.70

I don't know what was wrong with Tomcat 10, but 8.5.70 works fine with the same project.

---

UPD:

The problem was in imports. Tomcat 10 uses the ***jakarta.**** package rather than ***javax.****.

Thanks every one for your advises.

Comment: Nothing is “wrong” with Tomcat 10. Tomcat 10 uses the `jakarta.*` package rather than `javax.*`. In all other regards, Tomcat 10 is the same as Tomcat 9, both in parallel development, same features, same performance. Read [*Tomcat Versions*](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), and [*Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE*](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee) by Arjan Tijms, and [many other articles](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jakarta+javax.*+jakarta.*+package+name+change+ee&t=iphone&ia=web).

Comment: Remark that _"`javax.servlet.*` doesn't work anymore in Servlet 5.0 or newer"_ is the fourth paragraph of [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731512/11748454) to the question I already cited.